# How do I use category-specific colours?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

The Wordpress theme I am using (Multinews) comes with the ability to assign colour schemes to entire categories, so that all posts within that category take on the colour scheme that is assigned to that category.

However, I have added a couple of features to the design (ie a coloured dropcap on the first letter of the article) and would like to assign the category-colours to them, too.

For example, at http://www.mediatoday.org.uk/media/television-and-radio/2014/10/25/evan-davis-interview-with-russell-brand-was-fifteen-minutes-of-television-gold/ you'll see orange is the category colour, but the dropcap (the large R) is currently blue.

If you could please advise me on how to add the category-colour style to other features, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: And I'd really appreciate it if you could provide me some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So you have assigned color to the first letter and now you want to assign color to category name ..Is that the case?

Comment: The theme allows you to assign each category with a feature colour. The orange is the colour I have assigned to that category (the life and culture category), and the dropcap has been made blue because it is the colour that the :first-letter has been given in the CSS. 

How would I make it so that the dropcap for an article is the same colour as the category it is in. 

The css for my :first-letter is:

`article .entry-content address:first-letter {
font-family: "adelle", serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 7.1em;
line-height: 0.85em;
padding: 0px 0.05em 0 0;
color: #2c89d1;
}`

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By chance I worked on the same theme recently so I know what you're trying to find out. The thing is - the theme authors have that color built into their framework. They get the color selected depending on if the page or a category is being displayed and then they literally put it into the  underneath the menu.

If you inspect the HTML of your menu - the cat color is inside the HTML - it's not in any CSS atributes.

Try looking at the code of the menu and use the same principal:

```
if ($item->object == 'category') {
        $cat_ID = $item->object_id;
        $cat_data = get_option("category_".$cat_ID);
        $cat_color = isset($cat_data['color']) ? $cat_data['color'] : '' ;
        if ($cat_color != '') {
        $cl = $cat_color;
        }
    } elseif ($item->object == 'page') {
        $page_color = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'mom_page_color', true);
        if ($page_color != '') {
        $cl = $page_color;
        }
    }
```

it's the menu.php file under multinews\framework\menus folder

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to PHP so whilst I understand the principle, I'm not sure of how to alter it, to use it for the dropcap. Any help is appreciated, thank you!